# Math domain error due to disrespected constraint in scipy SLSQP minimize

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Consider a simple problem:

```
max log(x)
subject to x >= 1e-4
```

To solve the problem with `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import log

def func(x):
    return log(x[0])

def func_deriv(x):
    return np.array([1 / x[0]])

cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
         'fun' : lambda x: x[0] - 1e-4,
         'jac' : lambda x: np.array([1])})
minimize(func, [1.0], jac=func_deriv, constraints=cons, method='SLSQP')
```

The script encounters `ValueError` because `log(x)` is evaluated with negative `x`. It seems that the function value is evaluated even if the constraint is not satisfied.

I understand that using `bounds` in `minimize()` could avoid the problem, but this is just a simplification of my original problem. In my original problem, the constraint `x >= 1e-4` cannot be represented easily as bounds of `x`, but rather of the form `g(x) >= C`, so `bounds` wouldn't help.

Comment: I always use bounds for that purpose even at the expense of extra variables or constraints (but I use typically more advanced algorithms than scipy.optimize). E.g. in your case I would add `y=g(x)` and then put bounds on `y`. Instead you may get away with returning constraint function values that are (very) negative (i.e. infeasible).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen That's a solution, but I then have to come up with a modified version of `log(x)` that is very negative and is derivable even if `x` is slightly less than zero. May I ask what advanced algorithms do you usually use?

Comment: @peter I think he refers to the commercial tools like Knitro, Baron, Conopt and co. (or in general NLP-solvers supported by AMPL). An open-source alternative you can look into would be ipopt (or others if your complete problem is convex).

Comment: Yes you need to make your own safe log function. With an if statement this is not very difficult. Typically I use large scale sparse solvers including Conopt, ipopt etc (depends a bit what the client is using). Penalty for adding equations and variables is often low for those solvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we only care about the function value with `x > ε`, it is possible to define a safe function extending the domain.

Take the `log` function as an example. It is possible to extend `log` with another cubic function, while making the bridge point ε smooth:

```
safe_log(x) = log(x) if x > ε else a * (x - b)**3
```

To calculate `a` and `b`, we have to satisfy:

```
log(ε) = a * (ε - b)**3
1 / ε = 3 * a * (ε - b)**2
```

Hence the safe_log function:

```
eps = 1e-3

def safe_log(x):
    if x > eps:
        return log(x)
    logeps = log(eps)
    a = 1 / (3 * eps * (3 * logeps * eps)**2)
    b = eps * (1 - 3 * logeps)
    return a * (x - b)**3
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Plot of safe_log(x)]